# Delta 44: can you chain a MIDI thru cable to the PCI card?

Tags: midi

I just bought a Delta 44 PCI card/break out box and the seller had a MIDI computer cable chained into the PCI card.  While I could record on channels 1 and 2, 3 and 4 were very very quiet with a low signal-to-noise ratio.  Once I removed the MIDI cable, channels 3 and 4 were fine.

Searching through the Delta 44, the only reference to the word "MIDI" is within the context of the "MIDI Man" guitar/mic adapter that M-Audio sells; I couldn't find anything that would lead me to believe that the M-Audio supports MIDI.

Can someone confirm whether this is true or not?

Comment: doh.  Will edit.

Answer (score 1):

The delta 44 hasn't any MIDI i/o at all. I had  one a few years ago, so it's 100% sure (just look at the breakout box, there are only 6.35 jacks !). You can couple the D44 with a 24/96 which has a MIDI interface, or maybe use a Midi usb interface.

Comment: Sounds like he's got the wrong breakout box...

Comment: Not at all, he has the right one. The D44 breakout box has no MIDI I/O.

Comment: Right, which is why I'm trying to figure out where he's plugging in a MIDI cable.  It seems to me that he's got a breakout box for a different card that has MIDI I/O, and when he hooks this box up to his Delta 44, channels 1/2 happen to be connected correctly, but 3/4 are wired differently, and his MIDI cable is hooked up to one of the balanced input pins or something.  Just a guess.